# How can I compile multiple .asm files and create exe files for each one of them?

Tags: assembly, compilation, exe, tasm, dosbox

I have a lot of .asm files, in different folders.
Usually, to compile and link one file, we use two commands:

```
tasm /zi FILENAME
tlink /v FILENAME
```

I want to use the same compilation method, but on a mass of .asm files, all placed in different folders, and create an .exe file with the same name for each one of them.

Is there a line I can write in order to do this at once?
Should I write a short program to do it for me? and how?

Finally, I want to have .exe files that I can drag-and-play via DOS-BOX.

Thanks,
Naor.

Comment: Do you use `windows` to run `tasm` and `think`?

Comment: Create a script or batch file to do this. If this is windows, the batch file can do a for loop based on the existence of file names with a .asm suffix. I'm not sure about scripting languages for other OS. You may be able to create a large make file with target of "all" that would depend on all assemblies being done.

Comment: Yes, I do use windows, but don't really know much about .bat files. How is it done?

Answer (score 2):

If you run `TASM` and `TLINK` within Windows you can use a Windows-batch-file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem adjust the following lines to your needs
rem path to tasmx.exe and tlink.exe
PATH C:\Turbo.DOS\TASM.5\BIN;%PATH%
rem this directory and subdirectories
PUSHD C:\TMP\Tasm

FOR /R %%i IN (*.asm) DO (
    SET P=%%~psni
    DEL !P!.obj !P!.exe !P!.com !P!.map 2>NUL
    ECHO !P!
    tasmx.exe /t !P!,!P!.obj >NUL
    IF EXIST !P!.obj (
        tlink.exe /x !P! >NUL
    )
)

POPD
```

There is no `FOR` instruction in DOSBox. If you **must** use DOSBox for assembling and linking (64-bit-Windows), you build in Windows a batch file which builds a batch file for DOSBox:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem adjust the following lines to your needs
rem this directory and subdirectories
PUSHD C:\TMP\Tasm

>dosbox.bat     echo @ECHO OFF
>>dosbox.bat    echo IF EXIST X:NUL mount -u X ^>NUL
>>dosbox.bat    echo MOUNT X X:\ ^>NUL
>>dosbox.bat    echo X:

FOR /R %%i IN (*.asm) DO (
    SET P=%%~sni
    SET D=%%~psi
    DEL !P!.obj !P!.exe !P!.com !P!.map 2>NUL
    ECHO !P!
    >>dosbox.bat echo CD !D!
    >>dosbox.bat echo tasm.exe /t !P!
    >>dosbox.bat echo IF EXIST !P!.obj tlink.exe /x !P!
)

POPD
```

Run this batch file under Windows. You'll get a file `dosbox.bat` which you can run in DOSBox. I presume the path to `TASM.EXE` and `TLINK.EXE` is already known in DOSBox.

Comment: what if those `.EXE`s aren't known in DOSBox?
By the way, the `.bat` file works perfectly, so thank you! But I still need do find a way to get the `dosbox.bat` to work.
I do have the "most" emulator, which has those `.EXE`s in it's folder. Can I link them to DOSBox?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. You'll get at worst an error message. The **path** must be known. In DOSBox this can be managed by `MOUNT` and `PATH` on the prompt or under `[autoexec]` in the `dosbox-0.74.conf` (http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf#.5Bautoexec.5D). There is a `DOSBox 0.74 Options.bat` in your DOSBox program folder. Also, search on Google for "dos commands".